# Bootstrap table column value count

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-table

In my bootstrap table, one of the columns is populated from a data-field labeled "Available", and some of the rows in the column are null while others show YES.

I would like to take a count of how many "YES" appear in the column every 15 minutes and save it to an array that I can use to place into a bar graph.

How do I go about counting the number of times YES appears in the column?

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

```
        var count = 0;
        var yesCount = 0;
        var table = document.getElementById("table");
        var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            if (rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td").length > 0) {
                count++;
                if (rows[i].cells[yourCellIndex].innerHTML == "YES") {
                    yesCount++;
                    console.log(rows[i].cells[yourCellIndex].innerHTML);
                }
            }
```